# How can I create a pagination for this react app with jikan anime API?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, pagination, redux-toolkit

**How can I create a pagination to handle this api in React. I have tried but it does not work for me. I did not write any code. because I am not sure what to do anymore.**

```
https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime?page=${page}&limit=24
```

---

```
const {
        data: manga = [],
        isLoading,
        isFetching,
        error,
    } = useGetAnimeQuery(1);


    //destructuring objects
    const { data, pagination } = manga;
    const top_anime = data;



    if (isLoading) {
        return <Spinner color_1={"#141e30"} color_2={"#243b55"} />;
    } else if (isFetching) {
        return <Spinner color_1={"#141e30"} color_2={"#243b55"} />;
    } else if (error) {
        console.log("ERROR =>", error.message);
    }

    

    return (
        <section className="bg-gradient-to-r from-[#141e30] to-[#243b55]">
            <div className="container font-poppins">
                <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-3 place-items-center px-20">
                    {top_anime &&
                        top_anime?.map((anime) => (
                            <TopAnime anime={anime} key={anime.mal_id} />
                        ))}
                </div>
                <div className="button text-yellow-500 flex items-center justify-center mt-2 pb-2">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};
```